# How to transfer call to another url using plivo api and java

Tags: java, plivo

Am unable to transfer my call to another url . In plivo logs its shows :
   `"POST /v.0.1/TransferCall/ HTTP/1.1" 404 347 0.001610`

My Code is below:

```
import org.plivo.bridge.client.PlivoClient;
import org.plivo.bridge.exception.PlivoClientException;
import org.plivo.bridge.feature.call.CallFeature;
import org.plivo.bridge.to.callback.AnsweredCallback;
import org.plivo.bridge.to.command.*;
import org.plivo.bridge.to.response.CallResponse;
import org.plivo.bridge.to.response.TransfCallResponse;
import org.plivo.bridge.utils.PlivoUtils;
import org.testng.Assert;

Class CallTransfer {

    public void callTransfer() {

       PlivoClient newClient = new PlivoClient("v.0.1", auth_id, auth_token, plivo_url, true);
       Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
       parameters.put("Url", "myAppUrl");
       parameters.put("CallUUID", varMap.get("callUUID"));
       TransfCallResponse result = newClient.call().transfer(parameters);
       System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the url you have to specify either "aleg_url" or "bleg_url" and the "call_uuid" as such

```
params.put("call_uuid", "6653422-91b6-4716-9fad-9463daaeeec2");
params.put("bleg_url", "http://myxmlserver.com/xmldial");
```

Please check out this [link](https://github.com/plivo/plivo-examples-java/blob/master/Call/TransferCall.java) for the rest of clarifications.

Comment: Hi i also try this but transfer is not yet done . The parameters which we put in map and pass to the transfer method are not appended .... I dont know why the plivo api not getting the parameters through the passing map . In plivo logs it still shows "POST /v.0.1/TransferCall/ HTTP/1.1" 404 347 0.001610